# Как узнать тип загружаемого файла в Django?

Tags: django, файлы

Есть форма в которой загружается какой-то файл. Требуется узнать тип загружаемого файла. Что-то типа:

```
if file.pdf:
   print("smth")
```

Как это сделать в Django?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10937350/11214129

Comment: Самый надёжный способ — попытаться прочитать файл парсером интересующего типа (вроде pypdf). Если прочитался — значит этого типа, если выдал ошибку — значит какого-то другого (а какого именно — заранее не угадаешь, всякое может попасться)

Answer (score 0):

В Django есть валидатор:

```
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator
```

С помощью него можно указывать, какие форматы можно загружать:

```
models.FileField(upload_to='foo/', validators =[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['pdf'])])
```

Если посмотреть как он работает, то можно увидеть:

```
from pathlib import Path
[...]
extension = Path(value.name).suffix[1:].lower()
```

То есть достаточно просто передавать имя файла в класс `Path` и он будет возвращать тебе формат файла.:

```
>>> Path('file.pdf').suffix[1:].lower()
'pdf'
```

**Ответ:**

`from pathlib import Path
if Path('file.pdf').suffix[1:].lower() == 'pdf':
    print("smth")`

Comment: К сожалению, в некоторых случаях расширение файла может не иметь никакого отношения к реальному содержимому файла